# spacing in %d for inputs for scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

[image: sololearn]1. If I give the input `1234 5.7 elephant` will give the resulting output
`12  34  eleph` I know that * means it ignores the input field, %2d is up to 2 character will be considered. but why 34 is applied to the second conversion character %d it belongs to the first %d?
2. Can I include space, tab, newline in the scanf? what happens?
`scanf("% d %    d%s",var1, var2, var3);//`is this fine?

```
/* input: 1234  5.7  elephant */
/* output: 12  34  eleph */
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    char text[20];

    scanf("%2d %d %*f %5s", &x, &y, text);
    /* input: 1234  5.7  elephant */
    printf("%d  %d  %s", x, y, text);
    /* output: 12  34  eleph */

    return 0;
}
```

result expected: 12 elephant

Comment: @user3121023 It is invalid for scanf. It is valid for printf.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, '*' is an assignment suppressing character. I did not see it.:)

Comment: The `34` input does not belong to the first input, becuase it was halted at two characters. That's the point of the restriction `%2d` - so that the 3rd and 4th characters do not belong with it. No input is **forgotten**: if it is in the input buffer, it remains there until it is read.

Comment: vijay_ky Tip: post text as text, not as a picture.  Text as pictures attracts down-votes.

Comment: @chux yes %2d upto 2 characters and thanks for information on not to post text as image

Comment: Note (1) [Trailing white space in a format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-difference-between-scanfd-and-scanfd) and (2) [`scanf()` leaves the newline in the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer).

Answer (score 1):

> spacing in %d for inputs for scanf

In `scanf()` format a `" "` never fails.  It scans for *optional* white-space.

> why 34 is applied to the second conversion character ?

`"%2d"` consumes the `12` of input.  The 2 in the format limits input to 2 characters: `1` and `2`. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287666/spacing-in-d-for-inputs-for-scanf/57288102#comment101070670_57287666)
`" "` scans for spaces and sees none in the input.  Scanning continues.  `"%d"` scans in `34`.

> can I include space, tab, newline in the scanf? what happens?

Yes.  A whites-space in the scan format matches 0 or more input white-space.<sup>1</sup>

> `scanf("% d %    d%s",var1, var2, var3);`  is this fine?

No.  `"% d"` is not a valid `scanf()` conversion specifier.

> result expected: 12 elephant

This is curious. `printf("%d  %d  %s", x, y, text);` would print *something* out for `y`.  This is no *nothing* value for an `int`.

---

Tip: good code checks the return value from `scanf()`.

```
if (scanf("%2d %d %*f %5s", &x, &y, text) == 3) {
  printf("%d  %d  %s", x, y, text);
} else {
  puts("Bad input");
}
```

Better code does not use `scanf()`, but `fgets()`.  Far easier to handle errant input.

---

<sup>1</sup>White-space in a `"%[]"` specifier is handled different though.  It needs an exact match.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `"%d %d"` and `"%d%d"` (`scanf` format specifier) behave exactly the same.

Comment: @pmg True.  Surprising, to me, `"%d"` will consume leading white-space even if the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

%2d will get `2 lengths decimal` when you in put.

**If you try this...**

```
int x,y;
/* type  : 1234 */
scanf("%2d %d", &x &y);
/* var x : 12   */
printf("%d %d", x,y);
/* input : 12 34  */
```

**Or this?**

```
int x,y;
/* type  : 1 234 */
scanf("%2d %d", &x &y);
/* var x : 1   */
printf("%d %d", x,y);
/* input : 1 234   */
```

Then if you get limited length
It will record as next conversion character

and it depent on your space to!